# How to forcibly detach from the Skype client window using the Skype public API?

Tags: api, skype

Without re-running my app, I need to forcibly break my connection with the Skype client API window so that when I re-attach, Skype treats me as a brand new client app (a new process).  Are there any commands in the Public API or other techniques I can use to get Skype to "flush" it's API connection with me so I can redo the API discovery phase with a fresh start?

I need to do this to work around a bug I found in the Skype API that only happens when access authorization for my program is required from the user (first time run by a new user).  Here's the full details of the bug, which I posted on their Jira issue tracking system:

https://jira.skype.com/browse/SPA-760